# Windows 8.1 clicking on any desktop window doesn't bring that window to the front

Tags: windows-8.1, desktop

Not sure if this is a bug or a feature, but in my Windows 8.1 install, I can't seem to make any desktop window modal when I click on it. ie the window maintains its stacking order and doesn't come to the front. Most annoying!

Is anyone aware of a system setting I may have inadvertently switch off or...?

Comment: I have this same issue. It only started about a week ago. Did you get it fixed?

Comment: I am tagging along for this ride because I am experiencing the issue too. From what I can tell, it happened after the latest system update. I haven't found a solution yet, though.

Comment: Same here and no solution yet, very annoying.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it is related to Synergy. [Check this bug report](https://github.com/synergy/synergy/issues/4349).

Some people were able to fix it by uninstalling the KB3013455.

Comment: How about when it happens when you aren't using synergy?